# Wordpress 3.8.1 Multisite blog slug problem

Tags: multisite, slug, blog

Just installed Wordpress 3.8.1 multisite but can't remove the /blog/ slug.  I've tried all suggestions for older versions of Wordpress (including the solutions to the question posted on this site 6 months ago regarding removing from root) to no avail.  Anybody know how to fix this or if it's possible to fix?

I need two sites for a dual language website.  Could a solution be to just create 3 sites and use the root site as an interface to the other sites, or should I use an alternative CMS?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this in the following way.

Go to the "Network admin". Then Sites → Edit → Settings → Permalink Structure. Remove `blog` from it.

Then I removed `blog` from two lines in table which obtained as a result of the query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = "permalink_structure" OR option_name = "rewrite_rules"
```

Useful link on subject: [How To Remove The /blog/ slug From The Permalinks(URL) in WordPress Multisite Installation Without A Plugin](http://praveenlobo.com/techblog/how-to-remove-the-blog-slug-from-the-permalinksurl-in-wordpress-multisite-installation-without-a-plugin/)

This works with WP 3.8, I have not tried with 3.8.1

Note if you go to the main sites Setting -> Permalink you will still see `blog`, but it does not applied any more. But if you press "Save changes", `blog` slug will be used again. You need to redo previous actions again

Answer (score -2):

In your main install folder is: `wp-admin/options-permalink.php`

Change:

```
$prefix = $blog_prefix = '';
if ( ! got_url_rewrite() )
    $prefix = '/index.php';
if ( is_multisite() && !is_subdomain_install() && is_main_site() )
    $blog_prefix = '/blog';

if ( isset($_POST['permalink_structure']) || isset($_POST['category_base']) ) {
    check_admin_referer('update-permalink');
```

to:

```
$prefix = $blog_prefix = '';
if ( ! got_url_rewrite() )
    $prefix = '/index.php';
if ( is_multisite() && !is_subdomain_install() && is_main_site() )
    $blog_prefix = '/WHATEVER_SLUG_YOU_WANT_TO_CHANGE_IT_TO';

if ( isset($_POST['permalink_structure']) || isset($_POST['category_base']) ) {
    check_admin_referer('update-permalink');
```

Worked great for me, but you have to replace the slug with another I assume. (I did not try to leave it blank)

Comment: Editing core files is almost never a good suggestion. The changes you make will be overwritten when you update versions and may cause other problems with your site that you're not expecting.

Answer (score -2):

I couldn't get fixes for older versions to work with 3.8.1 either.

I just removed blog from the `options-permalink.php` - left it blank and it's working so far.... fingers crossed....

```
$prefix = $blog_prefix = '';
if ( ! got_url_rewrite() )
    $prefix = '/index.php';
if ( is_multisite() && !is_subdomain_install() && is_main_site() )
    $blog_prefix = '';
```

Comment: Are you saying that you hacked a Core file?