# Why is this "blog" keyword automatically added in permalink settings?

Tags: permalinks

Check the image attached here.
I want to remove this "default" blog category which is my site's default permalink settings.

From the google search that I did, I couldn't find much.

[image]

Comment: Do you have your WordPress configured as multi site?

Comment: Yes, it's a multisite.

Comment: This issue was asked several times before, for example here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107901/remove-the-blog-slug-from-wordpress-multisite-root-node 
and here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131582/wordpress-3-8-1-multisite-blog-slug-problem . Have you tried the solutions suggested there?

Comment: Will check those links once I am desk. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This one should supposedly give a good solution, to all those who land on this article.
http://praveenlobo.com/techblog/how-to-remove-the-blog-slug-from-the-permalinksurl-in-wordpress-multisite-installation-without-a-plugin/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove the blog slug from Wordpress Multisite root node](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107901/remove-the-blog-slug-from-wordpress-multisite-root-node)